# Assets & S3: Output Source Folder + Subfolder + Filename

Tags: assets, s3

I have a file on S3 uploaded with Assets. The full URL is:

`http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/source-folder/subfolder/file-name.pdf`

`source-folder` is the subfolder in the bucket where the Assets directory is set.

I want to output this path:

`source-folder/subfolder/file-name.pdf`

`{my_assets_field:server_path}` gets me `/subfolder/file-name.pdf`, but I can't find any way in the Assets field tag to dynamically output the source folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 2.1, you have to hard-code the source folder:

`source-folder/{assets_field:server_path}`

However, a solution for this is in active development for version 2.2.

Comment: `{subfolder}` only gives me the path *after* the source folder. So `{subfolder}/{filename}` gives me `subfolder/file-name.pdf`. I should emphasize that by "source folder", I'm referring to the folder set in Assets > External Sources > Subfolder.

Comment: Got it. In that case it’s not possible without just hardcoding it. I just went ahead and put it on the 2.2 list, which is in active development.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, B. If you update your answer about hardcoding, I'll accept it.